# Blazor Webassembly Window.visiblityStatus or JS interop

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

What is the equivalent of [Window.visiblityStatus (or Window.hidden)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState) in Blazor web assembly? I found this [GitHub issue from 2021](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37790) which effectively says:

> We've moved this issue to the Backlog milestone.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, but write some JSInterop to get the value.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yes apparently that's the only way. Unfortunately, we don't have proper `window` /DOM access in Blazor web assembly

Comment: There is a NuGet package below that issue, did you try that?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have proper window /DOM access in Blazor web assembly.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

JS Function added to index.html

```cs
//...
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.getDocumentVisibility = () =>
        {
            return document.visibilityState;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

And `Index`

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime js
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="bg-dark text-white">
    <pre>I'm @(currentDisplayStste) </pre>
</div>


@code {
    private string? currentDisplayState;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // Yield so we have done the first render
        await Task.Yield();
        currentDisplayState = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("window.getDocumentVisibility");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could do with a s/currentDisplayStste/currentDisplayState

Comment: Picky today ;-)